# calculated column: Make empty cells return as "No"

Tags: spotfire

Hi I have a calculated column which i would like to make sure that it either returns yes or No.

I can not get the empty cells to return No back, it comes out as 'empty'

this is the code I'm currently trying, any thing wrong?

```
case  
when [mycolumn]~="TEST" then "Yes" 
when [mycolumn]="" then "No"
else "No"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is no value, so the value is `null`. Note that a null value is different from an empty value `""`. Here it should always return a value ;)

```
If([mycolumn] is null or [mycolumn]="","No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty or null cells aren't covered by your cases...

```
case  
    when [mycolumn]~="TEST" then "Yes" 
    when SN([mycolumn],"")="" then "No"
    else "No"
end
```